# Jquery dropdown list set Id automatically

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails

**index.html.haml**

I have a form which has a dropdown list which has several fields. I want a customer to choose the field which has to be displayed in a form.And the rest of the fields should be hidded from the form.

```html
 .col-xs-12.table-responsive
  = form_for(@customer_detail) do |f|
.field-list
  = f.label :field_list,"Choose the fields to be displayed", class: "col-sm-3 control-label text-right"
  = f.select :field_list, options_for_select(CustomerDetail::INSERT_FIELD_LIST_CUSTOMER),{}, {prompt: "Field List", class: "checkbox_list_for_tax_org form-control form-width", "data-live-search": "true", multiple:"multiple"}

%table.table.table-striped
  %thead
    %tr
      - hash_value.each do |f|
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Customer Name
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Customer ID
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Address
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} State
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Email
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Website
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Service Tax No
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Local Sales Tax No
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Residential Type
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Attention To
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} City
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Pin Code
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Contact No
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Business Type
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} PAN No
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Central Sales Tax No
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Business Center
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Opening Bal
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Currency Type
        %th{id:"#{f[0]}"} Name
        %th.closed Address
        %th.closed State
        %th.closed Contact No
        %th.closed Pin Code
        %th.closed Delivery Address

  %tbody
    - @customer_details.each do |customer|
      %tr
        - hash_value.each do |f|
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.customer_name
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.customer_id
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.address
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.state
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.email
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.website
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.service_tax_reg_no
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.local_sales_tax_reg_no
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.residential_type
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.attention_to
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.city
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.pin_code
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.contact_no
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.business_type
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.pan_no
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.central_sales_tax_no
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.business_center
          %td{id:"#{f[0]}"}= customer.opening_bal
          - if customer.goods_address.present?
            %td.closed= customer.goods_address.name
            %td.closed= customer.goods_address.contact_no
            %td.closed= customer.goods_address.address
            %td.closed= customer.goods_address.state
            %td.closed= customer.goods_address.pin_code
            %td.closed= customer.goods_address.delivery_address
```

```js
$(function () {
$(".field-list").change(function(){
  var checked = $(this).find("option:checked").val();
  alert(checked);
  ($(this).val()).show();

});

});
```

The problem is I dont know how to set Id for each field. I need to display only the fields which has been selected in dropdown.can someone plz help me. thanks in advance!!

Comment: Your best bet is to create an `input` field attribute as and when an element is selected using javascript. try googling 'create form field using javascript/ jquery' instead of hiding and showing the fields.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var checked = $(this).val();
console.log(checked)
var currentSelectedArray = []
if (checked) {
 var selectedOption = [];
 var slectedIncrement = 0;
 jQuery.grep(checked, function(el) {
  if (jQuery.inArray(el, selectedValues) == -1)                  
   selectedOption.push(el);
   slectedIncrement++;
```

});